# How to download the iso file? Sorry for being this stupid

Tags: download

I want to install a Linux distro for the first time and I really like elementaryOS, but I can't seem to find out how to get the .iso. In the main page, where it asks for donation for the .iso, it doesn't let me do it. I tried with 10, 20, 30 and many custom dollar choices, but when I click on "Purchase elementary OS", nothing happens. What am I missing?

Sorry for bothering with such a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is supposed to bring up a dialog where you can enter your email and card details:

[image: Purchase Elementary]

If that isn't happening, you may want to check that your browser is not blocking Javascript.

Alternatively, you could set the price to zero, and then click the blue button, which will update to say "Download elementary OS":

[image: Set to Zero]

You can always buy it at another time to support the project.